# Debug LINQ-to-Entities lambda expressions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

According to

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015/

LINQ-to-SQL / LINQ-to-Entities lambda expressions are not supported.

> NOTE: Lambda expressions that require native functions to run (e.g.
>   LINQ-to-SQL) are not supported.

What other options are there for debugging ***LINQ-to-Entities*** lambda expressions?

I am already using the Entity Framework features for outputting the TSQL to either the Output window or to a file but what I would like is to be able to see the LINQ-to-Entities lambda expression evaluation in the Watch and/or Immediate window.

Comment: You can add them to your 'Watch Window' to monitor what the data is doing.  Usually you will get an 'error' but all you have to do is hit the refresh icon on the far right to spin up the information again.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like is to be able to see the LINQ-to-Entities lambda expression evaluation

LINQ-to-Entities expressions are simply *not evaluated* in .NET.  They are translated to TSQL, sent to SQL Server, where they are optimized and executed.

Comment: Can we expect built-in tooling in Visual Studio in the future for LINQ-to-Entities or what is the current consensus? Or is it not possible without having to reengineer .NET? Are there any 3rd party tools/add-ons?